# SI SoftEndOfStreamException: Stream closed between payloads when client disconnects

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a Spring integration server running on a *tcp-inbound-gateway* and a client that connects to the server using regular java sockets.

The client connects to the server, the server processes the request and then sends the response. The client reads in the response, then closes the connection using socket.close().

On the server side I have a *tcp-connection-event-inbound-channel-adapter* configured and I see this:

```
TcpConnectionExceptionEvent [source=org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection@2294e71d, cause=org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.SoftEndOfStreamException: Stream closed between payloads], [factory=crLfServer, connectionId=127.0.0.1:52292:5556:add2ff2a-b4ff-410d-8e60-d6b1a388044e]
```

Is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes; it's normal - we emit application events whenever an exception occurs on a socket, the `SoftEndOfStreamException` occurs when the socket is closed "normally" (i.e. between messages).

We could, I suppose, suppress that particular event, but some find it useful.